# Python, Hex and common file signatures

Tags: python, hex

I’ve got files from a system restore which have odd bits of data padded out to the front of the file which makes it gobbledegook when opening it.  I’ve got a text file of file signatures which I’ve collected, and which contain information represented like this at the moment:

```
Sig_MicrosoftOffice_before2007= \xD0\xCF\x11\xE0\xA1\xB1\x1A\xE1
```

What I am planning on is reading the text file and using the data to identify the correct header in the data of the corrupt file, and strip everything off before it – hopefully leaving a readable file after. I’m stuck on how best to get this data into python in a readable format though.

My first try was simply reading the values from the file, but as python does, it’s representing the backslashes as the escape character. Is this the best method to achieve what I need? Do I need to think about representing the data in the text file some other way? Or maybe in a dictionary? Any help you could provide would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode the `\xhh` escapes by using the `string_escape` codec (Python 2) or `unicode_escape` codec (Python 3 or when you have to us Unicode in Python 2):

```
>>> r'\xD0\xCF\x11\xE0\xA1\xB1\x1A\xE1'
'\\xD0\\xCF\\x11\\xE0\\xA1\\xB1\\x1A\\xE1'
>>> r'\xD0\xCF\x11\xE0\xA1\xB1\x1A\xE1'.decode('string_escape')
'\xD0\xCF\x11\xE0\xA1\xB1\x1A\xE1'
```